# Where is the "Double click on titlebar to minimize" setting located in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, preferences

I just updated my MacBook Air to Mavericks and I can't find the checkbox to enable the "Double-click on window title to minimize it" feature.

I thought I was in the `System preferences > General` pane, when I activated it, but that was in 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The setting is in System Preferences -> Dock

Comment: Indeed it is. What a strange place for that to be.

Answer (score -3):

The option is 'Double click on a window's title-bar to maximize'.

Comment: …on Windows, not OS X.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, in OSX, Mavericks, System Preferences - Dock, the option he is talking about is 'Double click on a windows's title-bar to maximize'

Comment: No, it's not — the option is *Double-click a window's title bar to minimize* and there is no maximise in OS X anyway.